# Error in sorting dynamically with a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I want to connect the SqlDataSource to the grid view and change the sorting data dynamically with a dropdownlist.
I used this code and it gave me this error:

code:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @order='Country' THEN Country  END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @order='City' THEN City  END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @order='name' THEN name  END ASC
```

error:
The CLR type does not exist or you do not have permissions to access it.

can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your ORDER BY clause to something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY
    CASE @order WHEN 'Country' THEN Country ELSE 1 END DESC,
    CASE @order WHEN 'City' THEN City WHEN 'name' THEN name ELSE 1 END ASC
```